# What is the area of $[r = \frac{4}{2 - \cos \theta}]$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polar-coordinates

It makes an ellipse, but I'm unsure where to go from here.

Answer (score 1):

The area can be computed in polar coordinates as
$$
\int_0^{2\pi}\frac12r^2\,\mathrm{d}\theta=\int_0^{2\pi}\frac12\left(\frac4{2-\cos(\theta)}\right)^2\,\mathrm{d}\theta
$$
If you prefer rectangular coordinates
$$
x=r\cos(\theta)=\frac{4\cos(\theta)}{2-\cos(\theta)}
$$
and
$$
y=r\sin(\theta)=\frac{4\sin(\theta)}{2-\cos(\theta)}
$$
Then
$$
1
=\frac{3x^2}{16}-\frac x2+\frac{y^2}4
=\frac3{16}\left(x-\frac43\right)^2-\frac13+\frac{y^2}4
$$
So the ellipse is
$$
\frac9{64}\left(x-\frac43\right)^2+\frac{3y^2}{16}=1
$$
One can use the formula $\pi ab$ for the area, where $a$ and $b$ are the semi-major and semi-minor axes.

Answer (score 0):

To express it in rectangular form, the objective is to rewrite your equation in terms of $x$ and $y$ variables.

Rearrange algebraically your equation to obtain $$2r - r \cos \theta=4$$
Then use the facts of $x=r \cos \theta$ and $r^2=x^2+y^2$.